# Android get error setListAdapter to custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i can not use `setListAdapter` for custom layout. like with this code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                testArray);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

after change `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to `R.layout.list_fragmen` thats resolved and dont get any error. both of those files are similar. but i can not change it.

simple_list_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@android:id/text1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="22px"
            android:layout_height="22px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="4px"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_light">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@android:id/text1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="22px"
            android:layout_height="22px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="4px"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_light">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat Result:

```
08-23 14:48:25.366      435-435/ir.tsms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Sorry I misread your question.

If you provide a custom layout, you also need to provide the id of the TextView that the values will be set to.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
        R.layout.list_fragment, R.id.text1, testArray);
```